# The usage of "in future" vs "in the future"

Tags: phrases, expressions, vocabulary

To refer to the future, can I use "in future" or do I have to use always the phrase "in the future"? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use *in future*. Without *the*, the part of speech of *future* is ambiguous and inferred as an adjective. Thus, the reader expects it to followed by, for example, a noun like *in future endeavours*. On the other hand, in the phrase *in the future* the *future* is a noun which is clearly announced by *the*.

Comment: @MartinKrzywinski Your assertion is not correct, you **can** use "in future", at least in BrE. The syntaxic context makes it clear whether "future" is part of the idiom or if it is the adjective.

Comment: Context needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "in future" as besides the 4 examples from Google books repeated below some 15 more can be checked. However, this is worth considering, specially in the light of a possible accent you might have chosen: from [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/future_1?q=future), in the idiom section, you can see that the BrE form is "in future" whereas the AmE is "in the future".

[Evaluation of historic, current and future water demand in ...](https://books.google.fr/books?id=cpGTJizPbbYC&pg=PA38&dq=%22in+future%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3nKXi4-3oAhVCz4UKHcx5B6sQ6AEIlgIwFw#v=onepage&q=%22in%20future%22&f=false) - 
McCartney, Matthew P., Arranz, Roberto - 2007 - 
It is likely that in future, as demand, and hence scarcity, in the catchment increases, there will be increased pressure to utilize water in the most economically efficient manner.

[Modeling Potential Impacts of Future Climate Change in …](https://books.google.fr/books?id=erS6BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&dq=%22in+future%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3nKXi4-3oAhVCz4UKHcx5B6sQ6AEIzwIwHA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20future%22&f=false) 
Gama, Arthur Chibwana, ‎Mapemba, Lawrence D., ‎Masikat, Patricia - 2014 - ‎
The APSIM results indicate that all models predict a brighter future for both integrating and non-integrating farmers, as mean maize yields are expected to be higher in future.

[The Future of Christian Mission in India: Toward a New …](https://books.google.fr/books?id=FaENBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA287&dq=%22in+future%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3nKXi4-3oAhVCz4UKHcx5B6sQ6AEI5QIwHg#v=onepage&q=%22in%20future%22&f=false) -
Augustine Kanjamala - 2014 -
“It is here the church/ Christians can play an enabling role in order to strengthen in future the solidarity movement of these subaltern groups of Indian society.”44 In contrast to the nineteenth century when missionaries were the only agents of …

[The Future of Secured Credit in Europe - Page 323
books.google.fr › books
- Traduire cette page
Horst Eidenmüller, ‎Eva-Maria Kieninger](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mUB1BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA323&dq=%22in+future%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3nKXi4-3oAhVCz4UKHcx5B6sQ6AEIgwMwIQ#v=onepage&q=%22in%20future%22&f=false) - 2012 
Security in future, multiple and partial receivables In modern financing practice, the assignment and creation of security in multiple and future receivables (as well as partial receivables) in a single transaction is commonplace. Accordingly, the ...

Comment: Fair point. However, the BrE usage sounds very awkward to AmE speakers. Both McCartney and Gama phrases sound clipped. Kanjamala's *to strengthen in future the solidarity movement* is just plain awkward with the *in future* better placed after *solidarity movement*.

Comment: Your last reference is not using "future" as a noun.